# How do the Arcane Archer fighter's Curving Shot and Magic Arrow features interact?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, fighter, arcane-archer

The [Arcane Archer fighter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/fighter#ArcaneArcher) (XGtE, p. 28-30) gains two features at 7th level. The first is Magic Arrow:

> At 7th level, you gain the ability to infuse arrows with magic. Whenever you fire a nonmagical arrow from a shortbow or longbow, you can make it magical for the purpose of overcoming resistance and immunity to nonmagical attacks and damage. The magic fades from the arrow immediately after it hits or misses its target.

The other is Curving Shot:

> At 7th level, you learn how to direct an errant arrow toward a new target. When you make an attack roll with a magic arrow and miss, you can use a bonus action to reroll the attack roll against a different target within 60 feet of the original target.

Curving Shot can redirect a missed shot with a magic arrow. Magic Arrow gives a normal arrow magic properties, but when it hits or misses the target, it becomes a normal arrow again.

Does Curving Shot apply to the Magic Arrow class feature, or only to magic arrows (+x arrows and Arrows of Slaying, for example)? Would any nonmagical arrow shot from a magic bow be able to do a Curving Shot?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Curving Shot can potentially be used every round thanks to Magic Arrow

[Jeremy Crawford, official 5e rules designer, clarifies the interaction of the two features here on Twitter](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/940665412164788224):

> *Arcane Archer; Curving Shot in Xanathars: Can be used every round for the cost of a bonus action cause all arrows fired from L or S Bow can be considered magical by 7th level? y/n?*
>
> **Yes.**

As you point out, the Magic Arrow feature lets any nonmagical arrow fired by the Arcane Archer from a shortbow or longbow be treated as magical during the attack. Curving Shot lets you use a bonus action to reroll a miss with a magic arrow to attack a different target within 60 feet of the missed target.

Together, this means that as long as you're shooting a longbow or shortbow and miss, you can use your bonus action to reroll that attack against a different target within 60 feet of the first.

---

#### If Magic Arrow's magic fades from the arrow immediately after it hits/misses, does that mean it stops being magical before the second attack?

Since you're "rerolling" the missed attack, I would personally interpret it as if the miss never actually missed, so the magic doesn't fade until after the rerolled attack is resolved. In universe, you're basically shooting at one target but your shot goes wide, and then the same arrow veers toward another target and either hits or misses.

Comment: I would say then the way that feature is presented is a bit misleading for me. If I can only redirect a magic arrow when it misses, and the class feature makes the arrow magic until it hit or misses, I understood that, as soon as the arrow missed the target it wouldn't be magical anymore and I would only be able to use the feature with magic arrows (+x or something). Thank you.

Comment: The best way to think about it is Read as intended it is suppose to work with your all your attacks from long or short bow. If you miss it still counts as magical for the next attack as the bonus action. Most likely it was just something that got missed on its transfer from u.a to xanathars guide. **WOTC employees are just as capable of human error as everyone else.**  it can get confusing. An example would be a mess up they had on the arcane archer 3rd level feature that stated it required a magical arrow. Hope the confusion is taken care of