# Does Arcane Shot overcome resistance or immunity to damage from nonmagical attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, magic, fighter

Would the Arcane Archer's [Arcane Shot](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#ArcaneShot-675) (*Xanathar's Guide to Everything* ch. 1; link requires access to XGtE in D&D Beyond), made using a nonmagical bow and a nonmagical arrow, count as a magical attack for purposes of overcoming a monster's resistance or immunity to damage from nonmagical attacks?

Comment: Related: [How do the Arcane Archer fighter's Curving Shot and Magic Arrow features interact?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140166/how-do-the-arcane-archer-fighters-curving-shot-and-magic-arrow-features-interac)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Only the effect applied by Arcane Shot overcomes non-magical resistance

As per the description given:

> #### Arcane Shot
>
> Once per turn, when you fire an arrow from a shortbow or longbow as part of the Attack action, you can apply **one of your Arcane Shot options** to that arrow.

And the options themselves:

> #### Arcane Shot Options
>
> The options **are all magical effects**. If an option requires a saving throw, your Arcane Shot save DC equals 8 + your proficiency bonus + your Intelligence modifier.

The options themselves are magical effects; therefore, they are the only part of the attack that overcome non-magical resistance. Arcane Archer later gets a 7th-level feature, Magic Arrow, that allows you to make your attacks magical for the sake of overcoming resistance.

[See also this post](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113364/how-do-i-know-if-an-ability-is-magical) on determining what is and is not a magical effect.

Comment: Deleted my earlier comment upon realizing that the Magic Arrow feature makes _all_ arrow shots magical. But I wonder if it can be argued that the Arcane Shots themselves are considered magical prior to level 7.

Comment: @mdrichey That's what i've specified in my answer - you "apply" one of your Arcane Shot options to your attack, and it states that just the option is a magical effect. Not the shot itself. Only damage done by the Arcane shot effect ignores non-magical resistance.